# unable to apply image policy against objects of type *apps.DeploymentConfig: No list of images available for this object

Tags: openshift

Every time I try to create a DeploymentConfig at the OpenShift Developer Sandbox from the repository :

https://github.com/GoncaloTMelo/os-training-devs/blob/master/vote-application/mysql/DeploymentConfig.yaml

I get the following error :

[image: Deployment Config]

Does this mean that this particular image is not available in OpenShift :
image-registry.openshift-image-registry.svc:5000/openshift/mysql:8.0-el8

If so, how could I use images available in the OpenShift registry, knowing that **registry.redhat.io**, requires authentication for access to images?

https://catalog.redhat.com/software/containers/search?gs&q=mysql

Thank you a lot for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically, the Pull Secret (registry token) that you are required to obtain prior to installing your OpenShift 4.x cluster.
If an ImageStream is created on the openshift project, it may not require additional authentication to access `registry.redhat.io`. However, if you create an ImageStream on other project that doesn't have a pull secret for the Red Hat registry, it is required authentication for accessing the Red Hat registry.

Here is the document I read.

https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/4.13/openshift_images/managing_images/using-image-pull-secrets.html