# Kafka Image Autoscaled to Zero showing "No revision" message

Tags: openshift

After several attempts :

[unable to apply image policy against objects of type *apps.DeploymentConfig: No list of images available for this object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77205533/unable-to-apply-image-policy-against-objects-of-type-apps-deploymentconfig-no)

I believe that I managed to build a Kafka image from this git repository:

https://github.com/wurstmeister/kafka-docker

Unfortunately my POD remains **Scaled Down** to Zero and it is shown as "No revision".
Nevertheless, I don't know why are no active instances of the application.

If anyone could help I would be very grateful.
Thank you.

[image: Build Kafka]

Comment: Do you want to use the Serverless for your kafka pod?

Comment: Many thanks for your feedback @hiroyukik. That wouuld be Kafka Pod.

Comment: I believe that the Kafka Pod should deploy with the strimzi Operator(or AMQ streams Operator). In your environment, it seems to deploy Kafka as a knative (Serverless). What made you decide to deploy with knative?